# What does it mean that a function $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is continuous on $c \in \mathbb R$?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, solution-verification, problem-solving

> **a)** What does it mean that a function $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is continuous on $c \in \mathbb R$? 
> **b)** Show that the function $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ given by
> $$ f(x) = \begin{cases}
> 3, & \text{if $x \in \mathbb N$};
> \\ 0, & \text{if $x \notin \mathbb N$};
> \end{cases} $$
> not continuous $\forall c \in \mathbb N$.

---

**a)** A function $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is continuous in $c \in \mathbb R $ if

$$\forall \epsilon \gt 0, \quad \exists \delta \gt 0; \quad c \in \mathbb R, \lvert x - c \rvert \lt \delta \implies \lvert f(x) - f(c) \rvert \lt \epsilon $$

**b)**  We know that $\mathbb N$ is not continuous in $\mathbb R$ because they are a set of isolated points.

Let's assume that the function is continuous. We have

$$\lvert x - c \rvert \lt \delta \implies \lvert f(x) - f(c) \rvert = \vert 3 - 3 \vert = 0 \lt \epsilon \quad ? $$

Got stuck here.

Comment: What does “266 / 5.000 Resultados de tradução” mean?

Comment: In your attempt on part b), are you assuming $x \in \mathbb{N}$ when you say $f(x)=3$?

Comment: @SangchulLee I was

Comment: Continuity is a property of a function, not of a set, so it doesn't make sense to talk about the continuity of $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Take some special $\varepsilon > 0$ to get a contradiction

Comment: Then what you did in part b) is read as: If you restrict your function $f$ onto the set $\mathbb{N}$ (i.e., only considering $f$ on the set $\mathbb{N}$), then that restriction $f|_{\mathbb{N}}(x)=3$ is continuous. This is obviously true. However, I am pretty sure what is asked in the question is to show that $f$, as a function on all of $\mathbb{R}$, is not continuous at each point $c$ of $\mathbb{N}$. Hence, you need to consider non-integral values of $x$ as well.

Comment: For what it's worth, both "continuous **on** $c \in \mathbb R$" and "continuous **in** $c \in \mathbb R$" sound really strange. Instead, one says "continuous **at** $c \in \mathbb R$". On the other hand, for a set of points one often uses **on**, as in "continuous **on** $\mathbb R$" (sometimes people say "continuous **in** $\mathbb R$", but this always seems a bit weird to me for some reason), but if you want to preserve as much as possible the other usage, then one would say something like "continuous at each point in $\mathbb R$".